# How to execute script before Apache basic auth?

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4

I need to protect some location with htpasswd and **that is working ok with**:

```
<Location /myloc>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "My Protected Area"
    AuthUserFile .htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

But I need to somehow bypass that Auth for example for url /myloc/loc1 but not for /myloc/loc2. The reason for this is that I want be able to get for example
loc1 and do some db search. For example:

```
"select Status From table where url=/myloc/requested_loc" (loc1 or loc2 or any name)
if Status == 1
   return 1
else 
   return 0
```

So scenarios is following:

1. execute some scritp before browsers prompt for user/pass
2. if script return 0 prompt for user/pass
   if script return 1 do not prompt for user/pass and open location

Some ideas:
1. I was thinking to modify https://github.com/winlibs/apache/blob/master/2.4.x/modules/aaa/mod_auth_basic.c
but I am not sure that is a good idea (I am sure that is terrible idea).

2. To have some ScriptAlias /myloc /opt/script.py that will check what I need in database and then if 1 open location if 2 send to browser 401 auth required.

And there my ideas ends.

**I am not looking for solution, just few ideas in what direction to pursuit this.**

**SOLUTION AND UPDATE**

I am so stupid I will not do Auth on /myloc at all. I will do Auth on dynamically created files loc1.conf, loc2.conf and so on, and then I will include that in apache virtual host configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  domain 
  ......
  Include /path/loc1.conf
  Include /path/loc2.conf
  ....
</VirtualHost>
```

[@HBruijn](https://serverfault.com/users/37681/hbruijn) gave me that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to investigate how Apache [merges directives and sets precedence](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging).

[`<Location>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location)  sections are processed in the order they appear in the configuration file so something like the following should allow unauthorized/unauthenticated visitors to access /myloc/loc1/:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    <Location /myloc/loc1/>   
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location> 
    <Location /myloc/>   
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "My Protected Area"
            AuthUserFile .htpasswd
            Require valid-user
    </Location> 
</VirtalHost>
```

From Apache 2.3 you can use [authorization containers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authz_core.html) to express more complex authorization logic.

Comment: Please take a look at my update. Thank you. You gave me great idea.